# How to convert Date & Timsestamp from one format to another & Compare in Linux Shell Scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to convert Date & Timsestamp from one format to another & Compare in Linux Shell Scripting

I have output from kubernetes pod age as `kubectl describe pods "podname" | grep Started | head -1 | awk '{ print $3,$4,$5,$6}`
'''
as  `07 Jul 2020 11:00:23`

I need to compare the above timestamp to the current timestamp & check if its greater the 15 minutes old in Shell Scripting

```
date +"%d %m %Y %T"
10 07 2020 11:12:42
```

I am trying to achieve as above. Please help for any pointers in date comparision

Comment: 1. Convert timestamp to seconds since epoch. 2. Compare seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the output into unix timestamp, i.e:

```
[usr@host ~]$ date -d "07 Jul 2020 11:00:23" +%s
1594116023
```

And compare with the current time:

```
[usr@host ~]$date +%s
1594383680
```

To wrap up, you could do:

```
kube_date=$(kubectl describe pods "podname" | grep Started | head -1 | awk '{ print $3,$4,$5,$6}')
kube_date_bash=$(date -d "$kube_date" +%s)
current_date=$(date +%s)
Difference=`expr $current_date - $kube_date_bash`

if [ "$Difference"  -gt "900" ];then
    echo "Older than 15 minutes.."
fi
```

Comment: You read my mind !!

But [ ] is having problems
expr: non-integer argument

./epoch.sh: line 11: [: : integer expression expected

Comment: This could be because of incorrect value of the `Difference` variable. Add `set -x` at the beginning of the script to print commands and their arguments as they are executed, and post it here. You may need also to add full path of "kubectl" in the script.